# Estou com o seguinte erro no volley " jsonexception : end of input at char 0 "

Tags: android, webview, volley

Envio a requisição o servidor se comporta com deveria não da erro, mais do lado do response me gera o seguinte erro "com.android.volley.volleyerror java.lang.runtimeException: bad url." estou usando o Android studio , WebView e o Volley.

Classe MainActivity;

```
 Map<String, String> postParam= new HashMap<>();
    postParam.put("username", "admin");
    postParam.put("password", "onblox");


    CustonRequest jsObjRequest = new CustonRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            "http//:192.168.0.13:8088/onblox/login",
            postParam,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    rq.add(jsObjRequest);
```

Classe CustonRequest :

```
public class CustonRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {
private Response.Listener<JSONObject> response;
private Map<String,String> parm;


public CustonRequest(int method, String url, Map<String,String> parm, Response.Listener<JSONObject> response, Response.ErrorListener listener) {
    super(method, url, listener);
    this.response = response;
    this.parm = parm;
}
public CustonRequest( String url, Map<String,String> parm, Response.Listener<JSONObject> response, Response.ErrorListener listener) {
    super(Method.GET, url, listener);
    this.response = response;
    this.parm = parm;
}

public  Map<String,String> getParm()throws AuthFailureError{
    return parm;
}
@Override
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String js = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return (Response.success(new JSONObject(js),HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response)));
    }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
    this.response.onResponse(response);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Você deve estar recebendo uma resposta vazia, verifique se `postParam` está correto, verifique também o código da parte do servidor e se o emulador está realmente fazendo a comunicação com o servidor. Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Depois de unas pesquisa mudei um pouco o codigo vou atualizar a pergunta . O corpo da resposta vem vazia , mais o headers não; Tenho que pegar o authorization que vem nele, o servidor ta funcionando ele recebe a requisição faz a busca no banco e me retorna certo mais quando chega no App que estou criando da erro de com.android.volley.volleyerror java.lang.runtimeException: bad url.

Comment: Provavelmente o seu emulador não está conseguindo localizar o seu servidor no localhost, para certificar, acesse uma url no google chrome pelo emulador que faça um get de alguma coisa, se caso não sair o resultado achamos o problema, dai então pesquise sobre como acessar o servidor localhost (a respeito do respectivo servidor que você está ultlizando) vindo do seu emulador

Comment: Já tinha testado com um GET no mesmo servidor onde temos um Controller que retorna true , onde esse Controller só serve para verificar a conexão e funcionou. Estou achando que pode ser como o volley recebe essa resposta. E TB não é o emulador estou testando em um smartphone .

Comment: Tem certeza que seu celular está conseguindo se comunicar com o servidor?

Comment: Pelo metodo Get que retorna um booleano sim.

Comment: Então não sei ajudar amigo, boa sorte

Comment: Valeu mano pelo menos você tentou isso já conta muito.